Side by side tables of equal height
I’m trying to create a figure or table similar to the image shown below.  The total width should span the page.  I do not care about the background color, it was only added to aid in this description.  The blue and green “subtables” should have the same total height (bottoms are aligned) and must share the vertical boundary (i.e. I don’t want that line thicker than the other vertical/horizontal lines).  However, they are otherwise controlled separately, i.e. they do not require the same number of rows and the row boundaries need not align.
I’ve made a number of very unsuccessful attempts at this using variations of subfigure, tabular/tabularx, minipage, etc.  The very much incomplete, but best attempt, I have is the following:
\begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X}
            \hline
            Description 1 & $a=x+y$  \\
            \hline
            Description 2 & $b=x+y$  \\
            \hline
            Description 3 & $b=x+y$  \\
            \hline
            Description 4 & some text
                \begin{equation}
                    c = x + y
                \end{equation} \\
             \hline
            \end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
            \hline
            Description 5 & some text
            \begin{equation}
                c = x + y
            \end{equation}  \\
            \hline
            Description 6 & some text
            \begin{equation}
                c = x + y
            \end{equation}  \\
            \hline
            Description 7 & $g=x+y$  \\
            \hline
            \end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

Goal:


IMHO the equations look better using \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}   \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{-0.5\baselineskip} {local to the figure).

Why don't you use only one table?
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{tblr}{
       width=\linewidth,
       colspec={X[c,t]X[3,c,t]*2{X[2,c,t]}},
       column{1,2}={cyan!10},
       column{3,4}={green!10},
       row{2-Z}={ht=1cm},
       vlines,hlines
       }
       \SetCell[c=4]{bg={}} \includegraphics[height=2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}&&&\\
       Text & $x+y=a$ &\SetCell[r=3]{} Text & \SetCell[r=3]{} {Text and\\$x + y=b$}\\
       Text & $x+y=c$ & & \\
       \SetCell[r=2]{} Text & \SetCell[r=2]{} Text and $x+y=d$ & &\\
       &&\SetCell[r=3]{} Text& \SetCell[r=3]{} {Text and\\ $x + y=e$} \\
       \SetCell[r=3]{} Text & \SetCell[r=3]{} Text and $x + y=f$\\
       &&&\\
       & & Text & $x+y=g$  \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{figure}
\end{document}



This is great, thanks!  I tried one table originally, but without success.  And this introduced me to a new table library.

@ScottB You're welcome and thank you for accepting my answer. Take into account that tabularray has the defect to slow down your compilation. If you have many tables, it's better to use traditional environments. Use tabularray only for the complicate tables like this one.

Looks tricky to get exact since it requires knowing the height of the taller columns. It is also unclear how to distribute the additional white space in either column. But you can manually increase the \arraystretch of the smaller and tailor it to match.
Code:
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.66} % This is my addition
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X}
            \hline
            Description 1 & $a=x+y$  \\
            \hline
            Description 2 & $b=x+y$  \\
            \hline
            Description 3 & $b=x+y$  \\
            \hline
            Description 4 & some text
                \begin{equation}
                    c = x + y
                \end{equation} \\
             \hline
            \end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
            \hline
            Description 5 & some text
            \begin{equation}
                c = x + y
            \end{equation}  \\
            \hline
            Description 6 & some text
            \begin{equation}
                c = x + y
            \end{equation}  \\
            \hline
            Description 7 & $g=x+y$  \\
            \hline
            \end{tabularx}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



I had considered something like this too, but hoped for a more "automatic" way, which I think CarLaTeX's answer provides (though you do need to know where the row breaks should be for it, so it still isn't totally automatic).
